# Multithreaded task dependency tree solver

Tags: c++, multithreading, graph, tree

I'm trying to bottom-up traverse a tree in parallel. The tree may look something like this:
[image]

I expect that each node will take ~seconds to process
This is the current version of the algorithm:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <filesystem>
#include <random>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include "thread_pool.h"

class node {
public:
    node(int value)
        : m_id(value) {}

    const std::vector<node*>& get_children() const {
        return m_children;
    }

    void add_children(const std::vector<node*>& child) {
        m_children.append_range(child);
    }

    void process() const {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution delay_dis(200, 1000);
        std::uniform_int_distribution error_dis(1, 100);

        // simulate a random delay
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(
            std::chrono::milliseconds(delay_dis(gen))
        );

        std::cout << "processed: " << m_id << '\n';
    }
private:
    int m_id;
    std::vector<node*> m_children;
};

std::future<void> parallel_bottom_up_traversal(node* root, thread_pool<>& pool) {
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

    for (const auto child : root->get_children()) {
        futures.push_back(parallel_bottom_up_traversal(child, pool));
    }

    return pool.enqueue([root, futures = std::move(futures)]() mutable {
        // process all child nodes first
        for (auto& future : futures) {
            future.get();
        }

        root->process();
    });
}

int main() {
    thread_pool<> pool(10);

    node* root = new node(0);
    node* n1 = new node(1);
    node* n2 = new node(2);
    node* n3 = new node(3);
    node* n4 = new node(4);
    node* n5 = new node(5);
    node* n6 = new node(6);
    node* n7 = new node(7);
    node* nd = new node(8);

    root->add_children({ n1, n2 });

    n2->add_children({ n3, n4, n5, n6, n7});

    n3->add_children({ nd });
    n4->add_children({ nd });
    n5->add_children({ nd });
    n6->add_children({ nd });
    n7->add_children({ nd });

    parallel_bottom_up_traversal(root, pool).get();
}
```

The algorithm above works reasonably well, as it traverses the graph in the desired direction, and processes each node accordingly, however, **in the case of the `8` node, we process it multiple times, which is undesirable**. How can I prevent processing a single node multiple times? I've tried locking the process function, but, even with a unique lock, I was unable to get it working correctly, here are the two outcomes I've reached:

- The thread just hangs and waits for another thread to process the node
- The thread returns from the original node without processing it (good), but it either gets stuck in a loop where it tries to re-process the same node over and over again until the other thread finishes processing it or, it just grabs the parent node and starts processing it, which is undesirable since, at the time it starts processing it, the child node hasn't been processed yet. **Ideally, the thread would start processing a completely different node that has no children left unprocessed.**

Comment: What you definitely should do is take the random generator code out of the `process` function. More off topic :  I think bottom up is not exactly what you would need.  Your current code will calculate node 8 multiple times. So sort your graph topologically and then you can just process nodes (from back to front) in an iterative loop (much easier to understand and debug).

Comment: Not sure if the topological sort would be optimal - while my nodes may take seconds to process, some of them may take more or less (+- 20 seconds) - wouldn't using a topological sort be detrimental in this case?

Comment: My guess is that the topological sort will be very quick assuming you don't have tens of thousands of nodes or more (I've worked with pretty large graphs, and it can depend on your datastructure). But in the end measurements will always be needed. After topological sort you can calculate all nodes without outgoing edges in parallel (then remove them from your graph) and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in a help thread in the [Together C & C++ discord server](https://discord.gg/tccpp). The solution is as follows:

```cpp
void process(Node &node) {
  std::unique_lock lock{node.mutex};
  if (node.has_been_processed) {
    return;
  }
  node.has_been_processed = true;
  if (node.children.empty()) {
    node.process();
    return;
  }
  std::vector<std::future<void>> threads;
  for (std::size_t i = 1; i < std::size(node.children); i++) {
    threads.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, process, std::ref(node.children[i])));
  }
  process(node.children[0]);
  threads.clear();
  node.process();
}
```

Note that the answer posted by Pepijn Kramer would also probably work.